# Liberar acesso aos dados de tabela do banco de dados para sistema de terceiro

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos

Existe alguma forma de liberar acesso a leitura de uma tabela especifica do banco de dados para um sistema de terceiro?

Por exemplo, tenho uma tabela chamada "clientes" e um sistema concorrente tem um recurso de emissão de boletos eficiente que pode aproveitar esses dados e precisa consultar minha base de dados para se manter atualizado e oferecer o recurso. Isso é possível?

Não gostaria de passar os dados do ftp do sistema, sendo que com um acesso limitado desse já seria suficiente...

Comment: Webservice foi criando exatamente para isso. Pesquise sobre o tema e as formas de criar um, sem dúvidas é bsm melhor que liberar o acesso ao seu db

Comment: Já que WS não seria considerado, você poderia criar uma base de dados, um utilizador com permissões apenas para leitura e fazer uma copia das tabelas que você deseja. Penso que há maneira de automatizar as copias das respectivas tabelas. Não seria uma solução ideal mas é uma solução suficiente.

Comment: Então, pensei na lógica de webserver apesar de nunca ter aplicado em alguma solução. Um detalhe é que o sistema terceiro irá gerar os boletos, mas de alguma forma terei que possibilitar de imprimir/visualizar no meu site/sistema, até esse ponto vejo o que posso fazer, crio uma view, monto um layout. O problema é consultar os dados, acessar banco etc. Vocês possuem alguma referência para que eu possa ler sobre? Obrigado!

Comment: Você poderia criar um usuário 'usuarioexterno' e garantir a este apenas o acesso à leitura das tabelas, sem precisar copiá-las e nem fazer qualquer outra alteração. Desta forma o outro sistema (externo) terá acesso aos dados que precisa e seu banco estará seguro, pois o acesso esterno nao poderá editar nada e nem visualizar as demais tabelas. O código abaixo resolveria: CREATE USER 'usuarioexterno'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha'; GRANT SELECT ON banco_de_dados.tabela1 TO 'usuarioexterno'@'%'; GRANT SELECT ON banco_de_dados.tabela2 TO 'usuarioexterno'@'%';